# How to delete Software RAID1 partition?

Tags: debian, raid, software-raid, raid1, debian-bullseye

I have Debian 11 server with software RAID 1 without lvm:

```
root@debian-base ~ # lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1     259:0    0  3.5T  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0    4G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0    1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme1n1p3 259:3    0    2T  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0    2T  0 raid1 /
├─nvme1n1p4 259:4    0  1.5T  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0  1.5T  0 raid1 /home
└─nvme1n1p5 259:5    0    1M  0 part
nvme0n1     259:6    0  3.5T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:7    0    4G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:8    0    1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:9    0    2T  0 part
│ └─md2       9:2    0    2T  0 raid1 /
├─nvme0n1p4 259:10   0  1.5T  0 part
│ └─md3       9:3    0  1.5T  0 raid1 /home
└─nvme0n1p5 259:11   0    1M  0 part
```

I want to delete `md3` partition and add its space to `md2`.
How to do that? (I can boot from rescue system)

Comment: what is nvme0n1p5 and nvme1n1p5 ? Can you delete them too ?